# What is the maximum amount of shells you can carry at once?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

In games of Fortnite, streamers such as Ninja often get the maximum amount of medium ammunition possible to carry, and light bullets as well. Does anybody know the maximum amount of shells you can carry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Small ammo cap - 999
- Medium ammo cap - 999
- Heavy ammo cap - 999
- Shells cap - 999
- Rockets - 12

Hope this helps! It may be hard to get max shells and heavy ammo types, but it has been done in modes like close encounters and sniper shootout.

Comment: Do you have any instances when you have seen this occur

Comment: Yes. I get high kill games and that therefore yields high ammo and resource counts. It happens every so once in a while where the players I kill are stacked

Comment: Have you ever seen this happen though, is there a video you have seen?

Comment: Just look up a high kill game of a famous very good twitch streamer or youtuber, like ninja or tfue

Comment: ninja often gets almost 500 shells every time, not 999

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the limit shown on the bar where your weapons are stops increasing at 999 the various amounts of ammo you can get increases beyond that. I have personally seen ammo increase easily past 999 into the 1200's. I have never noticed the hard limit myself but the wiki gives the following numbers although it isn't clear if these are for Save the World or Battle Royale though as I noted before I have noticed an increase above 999.

- [Light Bullets](https://fortnite.gamepedia.com/Light_Bullets): 6000

  > Ammo for weapons that use low caliber bullets. Typically used in weapons with a high rate of fire. You can carry up to 6000 light bullets.
- [Medium Bullets](https://fortnite.gamepedia.com/Medium_Bullets): 4000

  > Ammo for weapons using mid-range caliber bullets, tyically with balanced firepower and rate of fire. You can carry up to 4000 medium bullets.
- [Heavy Bullets](https://fortnite.gamepedia.com/Heavy_Bullets): 1000

  > Ammo for weapons that use high caliber bullets, typically for slow and powerful weapons. You can carry up to 1000 heavy bullets.
- [Shells 'n' Slugs](https://fortnite.gamepedia.com/Shells_%27n%27_Slugs): 1200

  > Ammo for weapons that use all types of shells, such as buckshot or slugs. You can carry up to 1200 shells 'n' slugs.
- [Rockets](https://fortnite.gamepedia.com/Rockets): 12

  No information is given in the wiki but my experience and that of others here tells us it is 12.

Comment: The rockets number is right; they made it really low to nerf guided missiles

Comment: Your answer is for save the world, bud. As a save the world player, I can verify these numbers as save the world ammo capacities, not battle royale caps

Comment: @Itaitui Noted, I know Battle Royale extends above 999 so I’ll have a look for exact figures when I can.

Comment: Battle Royale DOES NOT extend over 999

Comment: @Itaitui I have personally seen it extend above 999 so it may have been changed recently and I haven’t noticed.

Comment: Those values are for fortnite save the world

Comment: I agree, you cannot have 6000 light bullets

Comment: I think it is 999 additional bullets to the round that you already have

Answer (score -4):

The max amount of medium and light ammo is 999, heavy ammo is about 70, rockets are about 12, and shotgun shells are around 80 excluding any already loaded.

Comment: wrong, rockets are 12

Comment: You can have more than 70 heavy ammo, streamers often have more than 100